# Collision detection and damage using call method track

Tags: animation, events, godot-3

I'm currently implementing damage similar to these [two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mek4XtMhcMs&t=4s) [examples](https://www.youtube.com/@GameDevelopmentCenter), putting the damage logic inside the "call method" track of the player animation.

The problem is that sometimes the game just seems to skip the call method track. It doesn't matter if your FPS remains stable; it doesn't matter whether you set the physics FPS to 20, 30, 60, 120, 240 or even more.

At first, I thought it skipped single frames, so the solution was to add more call methods for the damage, but that didn't work.

I ended up calling the damage function 60 times in a 60 frame animation, and quite frequently the game just decided to skip them all.

Also, calling the function in code, even when applying the time delta, makes the enemy deal damage every frame.

And this seems to happen to some functions more frequently than others.

[You can download the first example from GitHub](https://github.com/harambert/3D_MeleeAttack) and test it. The damage functions skip at least 10% of the time.

Meanwhile, in my project, knock back or stunning functions seem to be skipped around 80 to 90% of the time. But the call method for anything related to the creation of bullets or instancing anything really, is never skipped.

How can I ensure this logic is applied reliably and never skipped?

> create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the problem. Show us the code and node setup needed to make the simplest possible demo where these call method track events get skipped

```
Func Anyfunction(): 
any non instancing logic, be it damage, movement, variables set to true or false
```

then go to the animation player, click add call method track, right click on a frame, select add track, select "AnyFunction()"  and then press play to open the game, if you instanced anything like damage indicators, sound or VFX, it will happen but if the function is calling anything non related to instancing logic, the game engine skips it quite often.

nodes required : AnimationPlayer and a script

another example:

all damage happens with

```
   #Damage 
func attack():
    var enemies = hitbox.get_overlapping_bodies()
    for enemy in enemies:
        if enemy.has_method("onhit"):
            if randf() <= criticalChance:
                var criticalDamage = damage * criticalMultiplier
                enemy.onhit(criticalDamage)
            else:   
                enemy.onhit(damage)
        if energy < maxenergy: 
            energy += 0.5
```

the archer enemy used to call a rigid body arrow when in the attack() and this fixed the problem of skipping damage but made the prospect of having hundreds of archers on the map impossible, with the new physics of the rigidt body arrow the lag spikes appeared at less than 60 archers... so they  do damage with a fixed area like everything else and an animated arrow that i added in blender. also i repeat, damage indicators or sound are almost if not always called, so i receive a damage indicator even tho i wasn't damaged because the area registered the hit and called the floating damage but didn't call the damage.

Comment: Most users won't click external links, watch YouTube videos, or download GitHub projects just to understand your question. You'll get more accurate answers, faster, if you edit your question to walk through the steps needed to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the problem. Show us the code and node setup needed to make the simplest possible demo where these call method track events get skipped.

Comment: In the project you uploaded, your animation calls `attack()`, which is not a valid function on Player.  `setStateAttack()` is, however - did you mean to call that?

Comment: setStateAttack() used to call the animation because I didn't know that you could set animation logic and input in the same function, so you must've found a relique from a few weeks ago or more, I'm not used to githhub so there's a lot of rogue files there, now everything does damage with the function attack(), or if you mean the link in the question... that's not my project, that's a free template from a tutorial. for a while now all my damage comes from func attack():
if enemy.has_method("onhit"):
enemy.onhit(damage)

Comment: @Tanaki also for some strange reason, the player I created never skips any function when calling with the animation player, but the one from the tutorials does, also the NPCS do, at first i thought the problem was the fps but i tried setting everthing up to the max, then maybe the problem was my code so i just deleted everything but the attack function for the npc and set it to cycle thro the same animation over and over again and even the the code had only 2 functions, sometimes it still skipped the damage